# Unable to make a component unmount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a little big personal project, and I figured out (after 3 months of code) that none of my components ever unmount.

I created a new-react-app to test in a brand new environment, and it didn't work either.

Here's my class :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import Test from './Test'
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      test: true
    }

    this.test = this.test.bind(this)
  }

  test(){
    this.setState({
      test: !this.state.test
    })
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
          </header>

          {this.state.test ? <Test /> :null}
          <button onClick={this.test}/>
        </div>
      )

  }
}

export default App;
```

here's console's result

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7K2FU.png)

Thank you for your time !

**EDIT : I discovered that in every class I always called component*S*WillUnmount instead of componentWillUnmount... thanks everybody**

Comment: did you maybe want to show us the component that isn't unmounting?

Comment: You can confirm if your component unmount by using the `componentWillUnmount()` life cycle method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you toggle the `test` state, your `Test` component does unmount. You maybe looking at some incorrect information. See the snippet below

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      test: true
    }

    this.test = this.test.bind(this)
  }

  test(){
    this.setState({
      test: !this.state.test
    })
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            
            <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
          </header>

            {this.state.test ? <Test /> :null}
  <button onClick={this.test}/>
        </div>
      )

  }
}

class Test extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('mounted');
  }
  componentWillUnmount () {
   console.log('unmounting');
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <div className="test">
          Hello
        </div>
      )

  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"/>
```